# Building ejb jar weblogic 103 and ANT

Tags: ant, ejb, weblogic

I am using wlappc command in ant script to build jar and I have weblogic.jar in classpath.

```
ejb3Compile:
     [echo]  "Compiling EJB"
   [wlappc] Created working directory: /var/tmp/appcgen_1423590774747_VMS.jar
   [wlappc] java.lang.RuntimeException: error in finding weblogic.Home
   [wlappc]     at weblogic.Home.getInstance(Home.java:91)
   [wlappc]     at weblogic.Home.getPath(Home.java:97)
   [wlappc]     at weblogic.ejb.container.persistence.InstalledPersistence.setInstallationLocation(InstalledPersistence.java:299)
   [wlappc]     at weblogic.ejb.container.persistence.InstalledPersistence.initialize(InstalledPersistence.java:134)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

- Use ant supplied within the weblogic install, this should know the home by default:

  `<install dir>/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/bin/ant`
- Add the weblogic home as a parameter to ant:

  `ANT_OPTS=-Dweblogic.home="<install_dir>/wlserver_10.3"`

Replace `<install_dir>` with the path to your Oracle install directory.

Comment: tried two options, didnt work... for second option I use set ANT_OPTS=-Dweblogic.home="<install_dir>/wlserver_10.3" . didnt work

Comment: `-Dweblogic.home=/opt/ora/mw/wlserver_10.3` has always worked for me, you may also want to try `-Dmw.home=/opt/ora/mw`. Don't use the literal string <install_dir>

Comment: [wlappc] weblogic.ejb.container.persistence.PersistenceException: [EJB:011001]Installation file /export/appl/sficli/sbea/weblogic1036/wlserver_10.3/=/lib/persistence/persistence.install does not exist. Could not initialize EJB container-managed persistence.

Comment: It should be `wlserver_10.3/server/lib/persistence/persistence.install` not `wlserver_10.3/=/lib/persistence/persistenc‌​e.install` you have an `=` in there somehow